# Matching points to grid-cells - using join attributes by location

Tags: point, attribute-joins, spatial-join, vector-grid

I have point data in a shapefile covering most of Africa. I've made 0.1x0.1 grids using the `make grid` option from QGIS and now I want to link the grid_id to my point data. Below you will find a picture of all my data points an the grid and a zoom in where the grids can be distinguished from each other - I want every point to get assigned a grid_id number base don which grid they are located in. [image: Complete map] [image: zoom in]

I've tried using `join attributes by location`, where my input layer was the point file and my join layer was the grids I've just made. I've experimented with other geometric predicates, but I would think I need to use the `within` option. However, when I run the program, he does not match any of the grid ids to my point data.

I've also tried using the MMQGIS `spatial join` option, but this won't allow me to select a spatial operation once I've selected the layers I want to combine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to link a grid_id to point data?

Comment: Check if both layers have the same coordinate reference system (CRS) (in each layers property).

Comment: @geozelot They do, both have EPSG 4326 - WGS 84.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've researched your trouble with the MMQGIS spatial join option. From what i've seen the problem is that the grid you've generated was a line layer. The MMQGIS does not support a spatial join operation between a point layer and a line layer. In the MMQGIS documentation says that:

"Spatial Operation: Indicates the spatial relationship that should be used in the operation. Some relationships are not available for some combinations of shapes (ex: there is no within relationship when joining a polygon target layer with a point join layer)"

In the `make grid` process you can set the type of grid to generate either squares (lines) or squares (polygons).If you generate a polygon type grid then you can set the spatial operation and run the process.

Here the polygon type grid and the point layer
[image]

And here i can set the spatial join without problem

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Lcortes ! This solved my problem :)